# Use table in database like in excel

Tags: mysql-5.6, c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm writing a program for my client in C# Winform. And the client gave this excel sheet.

**Process**

I have a table that used to calculate BULK amount of alcohol by "DIP" and "SLIDE".
In excel I need to select the specific DIP and SLIDE to get the BULK. I need to do the same thing in the database.

I exported a table from excel to MySQL table. 
[image: excel sheet]
[image: table in database]

I can get the BULK amount by this query

`SELECT SLIDE 0.8 FROM tbl_vat_01_alcohol_esa WHERE DIP = 212;`

**Requirement**

I need to get the DIP and/or SLIDE when I enter BULK amount. I wanna know how to do it? or Is it possible to do that kind of work in this table? or do I need to change the table structure or something.

`OR`

How to access the excel sheet from C# winform. I mean, If I make a form that contain 3 textbox for DIP, SLIDE and BULK.
When I enter DIP and SLIDE I get BULK and when I enter BULK I get DIP and SLIDE...

Is it possible? If it is, How to achieve that? `OR` Is there any other method.

I'm new to StackExchange and Database!

Comment: start with connecting to the mysql server [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618015/how-to-connect-to-mysql-database) and get the row/s using the select query you have in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you have is a cross-table you need to uncross it.

create a table with three columns `bulk`,`dip`,and `slide`, put each cell of the excel table into a row of this table.

then you can query like

`select bulk from bdstable where slide=0.8 and dip=212`

Comment: thank you for the respond. your answer looks promising. But, what about using the excel file instead of creating table in database? Can I read the cell value using c#? I only need to read the values, not to update or something.

Comment: off topic in on this stack exchange, ask on stack overflow about how to do OLE

Comment: Sorry for late. 1st of all, I didn't know what kind of table is that. I mean the name. And I searched for 'how to convert cross table to list table' Then I found this 'AWESOME' Add-In for Excel called 'KUTOOL' This Add-In saved my time. My excel sheet has hundreds of data, I can't make one by one. Thank you SO MUCH @Jasen.